# PHP Escaping double Quote on echo with onclick

Tags: javascript, php

Please notice the `addslashes($model->subject)` part in the code below. If the subject contains single quote, it works fine but if it has double quote, javascript generates error and treats that the `onclick` method ends on the double quote character. How to solve that error?

```
    $string.=" <a href='#' class='' data-toggle='modal' "
    . "onclick=\"to_edit('" . $model->id . "','" . $model->doc_type_level_1 . "','" . $model->doc_type_level_2 . "','" . $model->doc_type_level_3 . "','" . addslashes($model->subject) . "','" . $model->date . "',"
    . "'" . $model->date_release . "','" . $model->is_confidential . "'"
    . ")\" "
    . "data-target='#modal_doc' ><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span></a>";
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use `addcslashes('str', "'");` to escape only single quotes.

Comment: try this instead of addslashes : `,\\\'" . ($model->subject) . "\\\',`

Comment: @IvanBolnikh I need to escape double quotes.

Comment: @lalithkumar String does not have quote all the time. Only few records.

Comment: when you are remove the addslashes what is happening ?same error?

Comment: @lalithkumar. It gives error because we added slashes to all records even if others don't need it.

Comment: Then you need to use `stripslashes($model->subject)` instead of addslashes

Answer (score 0):

You should use `htmlspecialchars` to convert these entities, use following code:

```
htmlspecialchars($model->subject, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: i used this `htmlspecialchars($model->subject,ENT_QUOTES)` now it works on double quote and not in single quote.

Comment: Sorry my code was incorrect, please try with the edited code.

Comment: Yes I know the error on the code you've given. After trying, it works on double quote now but not in single quote.

Comment: documentation says if you use this method with `ENT_COMPAT` as second parameter then "Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone." and if you use `ENT_QUOTES` then "Will convert both double and single quotes.". So ideally it should convert both with option `ENT_QUOTES`